# Can't have a form in modal - Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a a modal with a form that uses slots. I want to keep the design on the modal screen and put the submit buttons in the footer slot.

For some reason, it does not let me open a form tag in the body slot and then close it in the footer.

One solution is putting everything in the body tag but then I miss out on the footer style.

Any solutions to do this?

```
      <h3 slot="header">Add Folder</h3>
                <span slot="body">



                    <form @submit.prevent="addFolder">


                        <div class="form-group" v-bind:class = "(this.errors.filter(e => e.name === 'name').length > 0) ?'form-error':'' ">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" aria-label="name" v-model="folder.name" />
                        </div>



                </span>

                <span slot="footer">

                    <input type="submit" class="btn-success js-scroll-trigger" value="Add" />
                    <button class="btn-edit js-scroll-trigger" @click="showAddFolderModal = false">Cancel</button>


                    </form>

                </span>



            </modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it in the body is not one solution but it is the valid syntax, Unless the HTML  syntax has changed, which we doubt, you cannot start a tag anywhere and end it wherever.

Now to your solution, have you tried having the whole
Footer inside the body? 
Another possible way is to not have the type=submit button and just have a normal button and handle its click. In your on click handler you will already have the form data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe move the form outside, to contain both slots. No sure if something like this will work for you because your template is not complete but:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <modal>
      <h3 slot="header">Add Folder</h3>
      <form @submit.prevent="addFolder">
        <span slot="body">
          <div class="form-group" v-bind:class = "(this.errors.filter(e => e.name === 'name').length > 0) ?'form-error':'' ">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" aria-label="name" v-model="folder.name" />
          </div>
        </span>

        <span slot="footer">
          <input type="submit" class="btn-success js-scroll-trigger" value="Add" />
          <button class="btn-edit js-scroll-trigger" @click="showAddFolderModal = false">Cancel</button>
        </span>
      </form>
    </modal>
  </div>
</template>
```